# How should i get image url in my category tree?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, event-observer

as

```
<?php
class Ahybemeir_CategoryObserver_Model_Observer{
  public function updateTopMenuJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
      $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
      $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
      $recursionLevel = 3; // Add recursion level
      $storeId = 1; // Add your Store ID for which you want to get category tree
      $node = '';
      $categoryTreeData = $this->getCategoryTree($recursionLevel, $storeId);
      $arr = json_encode($this->getCategoryTree(3));
      echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);
  echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$arr."');</script>");
  file_put_contents("cat_node.json", $arr);
}

protected function getCategoryTree($recursionLevel, $storeId = 1)
{
    $parent = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
    $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
    /* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree */

    $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
        ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
        ->getChildren();
    $collection = $tree->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('description');
    $tree->addCollectionData($collection, false, $parent);

    $categoryTreeData = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        if ($node->getIsActive()) {
            $categoryTreeData[$node->getData('entity_id')] = $this->getNodeChildrenData($node);
        }
    }

    return $categoryTreeData;
}

protected function getNodeChildrenData(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
{
    $categoryData = array(
      'title' => $node->getData('name'),
      'url'   => $node->getData('url_key'),
      'id'    => $node->getId(),
      'description' => $node->getData('description'),
      'img' => $node->getImageUrl(),
      // 'mega_menu1'=> $node->getData('mega_menu')
      'mega_menu'=> 'false'
    );

    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $childNode) {
      if (!array_key_exists('children', $categoryData)) {
          $categoryData['mega_menu'] = 'true';
          $categoryData['children'] = array();
      }

        $categoryData['children'][$childNode->getData('entity_id')] = $this->getNodeChildrenData($childNode);
    }
    return $categoryData;
}
} // End of Class
?>
```

Comment: I want o get image data in my json tree. so that i will use it on frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add category images change

```
$collection = $tree->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('description');
$tree->addCollectionData($collection, false, $parent);
```

To:

```
$collection = $tree->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('description', 'image'));
$tree->addCollectionData($collection, false, $parent);
```

**Edit:**

For the category images are store in `media/catalog/category` folder, so you can use this:

```
$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/category/' . $node->getImage();
```

Comment: Thank you..but now i get only image name..noy getting full url, so that it will display on frontend.Now its just displaying a curupted image.

Comment: Please help me for getting the image url,so that i will display it on frontend.

Comment: Updated answer.