# Fetch sub categories of parent Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I am attempting to **fetch the sub-categories of a parent category in Magento 1.9.2**. I've created a file 'subcategories.phtml' and reference this in a static block. I know the reference in the static block works as it shows the words 'test'.

However, if I update the file with the code below it shows only a blank page. Can anyone please advise an update to get this working?

```
<?php 
//If there are sub categories
$categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
$categoriescount = $this->getCurrentChildCategories()->count();
if ($categoriescount > 0): 
?>
<div class="sub-category-container">    
    <?php 
    //Loop through categories
    foreach ($categories as $category):
    ?>
    <div class="sub-category">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-image">
        <?php 
        // If there is a thumbnail set for the category - Display it
        if($imgUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()):?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".$imgUrl ?>" width="220" height="110" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        <div class="inner-sub-category">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="sub-link"><?php echo $category->getName()?></a>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="btn"><span>View All</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php else:?>
<p>No Sub Categories</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please let me know if you found a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can used recursive function to get sub category within sub category to nth level.This code might help you i create a function in which i pass category id and check whether it has sub category or not.

```
$rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
if (Mage::getStoreConfig('customconfig_options/section_one/custom_field_nine') != '') {
    $array= '<ul>';
    foreach ($cat_name as $key=>$c) {
        $array .= '<li>'.
        $c . "<input type='radio' name='category' id='category' style='margin-left:5px' value='".$key."'>\n";
        $array .= '</li>';
    }
    $array.= '</ul>';
    echo $array;
} else {
    function get_categories($categories) {
        $array= '<ul>';
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
            $count = $cat->getProductCount();

            $array .= '<li>'.
            $category->getName() . "<input type='radio' name='category' id='category_".$category->getId()."' style='margin-left:5px' value='".$category->getId()."'>\n";
            if ($category->hasChildren()) {
                $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
                $array .=  get_categories($children);
            }
            $array .= '</li>';

        }
        return  $array . '</ul>';
    }
    echo  get_categories($categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categoryId = 5;?>
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) ?>
<?php $_categories = $category->getChildrenCategories() ?>

<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php if($_category->hasChildren()):?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                                <?php $_category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                <?php if($_category2->hasChildren()):?>
                                <?php $_subcategories2 = $_category2->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach($_subcategories2 as $_subcategory2): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory2) ?>"><?php echo $_subcategory2->getName() ?></a>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get sub-category data in this way ... but therefor you have to change your HTML a bit. You may inspect `$cat->getData()` to see all available data.

From [How should i get image url in my category tree?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178001/how-should-i-get-image-url-in-my-category-tree/178004#178004)

```
$storeId = 3;
$recursionLevel = 3;

$parent = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
$tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');
/* @var $tree Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree */

$nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
    ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
    ->getChildren();
$collection = $tree->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$tree->addCollectionData($collection, false, $parent);

foreach ($collection as $cat) {
    # inspect possible data and adjust your html
    var_dump($cat->getData());
    break;
}
```

---

Another way to get all to data for categories is this ... [How to write function for getting subcategories of particular category?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182618/how-to-write-function-for-getting-subcategories-of-particular-category/182698#182698)

```
public function getCategories()
{
    $categoryId = 2;
    $categoryTree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($categoryId);

    $array = array();
    foreach ($categoryTree as $category) {
        $array[$category->getPathId()] = $category->getName();
        $array = array_merge($array, $this->_getChildren($category));
    }
}

public function _getChildren($category, $array = array())
{
    if ($category->getChildrenCount()) {
        foreach ($category->getChildren() as $child) {
            $array[$child->getPathId()] = $child->getName();
            $this->_getChildren($child, $array);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your subcategories.phtml , paste the below code.

```
<?php 
  $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
  $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
  $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
  $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId);
?>
<?php foreach ($children as $category): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $children->getUrl() ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $children->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
      </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Not working for me in 1.9.2

Comment: In which page , u want to fetch the subcategory ??